# How set seekbar max value(video duration)?

Tags: java, android, seekbar

Cant set seekbar max value, it must be a video duration, but if look to my code, it show error, because cannot be applied (long), it must be (int). The same when I return value.
Anyone have idea how fix it?

```
 DiscreteSeekBar discreteSeekBar1 = (DiscreteSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.discrete1);
        discreteSeekBar1.setMin(0);
        **discreteSeekBar1.setMax(mVideoView.getDuration());**
        discreteSeekBar1.setNumericTransformer(new DiscreteSeekBar.NumericTransformer() {
            @Override
            public int transform(int value) {
                **return  mVideoView.seekTo(mVideoView.getCurrentPosition() + value);**
            }
        });
```

Comment: long != int - that's why. Besides that you should clarify what your import for `DiscreteSeekBar ` is.

Comment: I know it. I want set maxValue to seekbar and it must be videoDuration, but I dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely cast it to `int`. There's no way your video duration exceeds `Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2,147,483,647`. It would have to be 2,147,483 seconds long

`discreteSeekBar1.setMax((int) mVideoView.getDuration());`